# Drop in stored procedure not executed if stored procedure failed in middle of execution

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure create_mv(). The query is basically like this.

```
create procedure create_mv()
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
drop my_mv1();
drop my_mv2();
drop my_mv3();

create materialized view my_mv1 as...;
create materialized view my_mv2 as...;
create materialized view my_mv3 as...;
end;
$$;
```

The my_mv1, my_mv2, and my_mv3 take much disk space so i want to drop them first before i create them again. But the stored procedure failed to execute when creating my_mv2 because disk space is full.

Then i do a check and realized that my_mv1, my_mv2, and my_mv3 is still there. Why it doesn't dropped?
Do i use stored procedure in a wrong way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can add the “if exists” clause: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropmaterializedview.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that but the materialized view still exists. The materialized view dropped successfully if the stored procedure run successfully.

Comment: Oh, so your problem isn’t that the views aren’t dropped. In reality, the transaction needs to be able to roll back if there is an error, so while the views are no longer visible, they will not be dropped until the COMMIT or the end of the function. Try committing before creating the new views

Comment: But i don't use transaction. Does the stored procedure using transaction implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is an exception the transaction cannot be committed, so the changes have to be rolled back eventually.

You can try to catch any exception by enclosing each statement in a block like:

```
...
BEGIN
  DROP ...;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
...
BEGIN
  CREATE ...;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
...
```

That way an exception doesn't bubble up.

Single statements can however still fail. So at the end you won't really know what statement was successfully executed and which failed leaving the database in a probable inconsistent state. So if I where you, I'd rethink the whole concept of putting all that in a (single) procedure (or consider buying a bigger disk).